# Generics IAbstract<T> inherits from IAbstract

Tags: c#, generics

I am trying to achieve something like this:

```
interface IAbstract
{
    string A { get; }
    object B { get; }
}

interface IAbstract<T> : IAbstract
{
    T B { get; }
}

class RealThing<T> : IAbstract<T>
{
    public string A { get; private set; }
    public T B { get; private set; }
}
```

So I can do something like this:

```
RealThing<string> rt = new RealThing<string>();
IAbstract ia = rt;
IAbstract<string> ias = rt;
object o = ia.B;
string s = ias.B;
```

Is this possible?

Comment: A good example of this exact pattern in the .NET framework is [`IEnumerable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerable.aspx) and [`IEnumerable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0(v=vs.110).aspx) where `IEnumerable` has `IEnumerator GetEnumerator()` and `IEnumerable<T>` does the exact same thing you are doing with your properties with `IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Very nearly. Three things:

- You should use `new` in `IAbstract<T>` to indicate that you know you're hiding an existing member:

  ```
  new T B { get; }
  ```

  But even without that, you'll still only get a warning.
- You need to implement the `IAbstract.B` within `RealThing`, which you should almost certainly do using explicit interface implementation, delegating to the strongly-typed member:

  ```
  object IAbstract.B { get { return B; } }
  ```
- Within your test code, you need to specify a type argument for `RealThing`:

  ```
  RealThing<string> rt = new RealThing<string>();
  ```

This is fine, and even a reasonably common pattern for times where you want to be able to get a non-generic form of an interface.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, with little changes

```
interface IAbstract
{
    string A { get; }
    object B { get; }
}

interface IAbstract<T> : IAbstract
{
    new T B { get; }
}

sealed class RealThing<T> : IAbstract<T>
{
    public string A { get; private set; }
    public T B { get; private set; }

    object IAbstract.B
    {
        get { return B; }
    }
}
```

so you can write

```
var rt = new RealThing<string>();
IAbstract ia = rt;
IAbstract<string> ias = rt;
object o = ia.B;
string s = ias.B;
```

Comment: Shouldn't the `B` property on `IAbstract<T>` be marked with the `new` keyword to make the shadowing explicit?

Answer (score 1):

Actually the `System.Collections.IEnumerator` and `System.Collections.IEnumerator<T>` interfaces do that. When you implement `IEnumerable<T>`, you will have to implement one of the `Current` properties explicitly, usually you will pick the non-generic one for that:

```
object IEnumerable.Current
{
    // this calls the implicitly implemented generic property
    get { return this.Current; }
}

public T Current
{
    get { return this.current; } // or however you want to do it
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In this case you don't even need two interfaces. Just mark the interface as covariant (supported since C# 4):

```
interface IAbstract<out T>
{
    string A { get; }
    T B { get; }
}
```

and use `IAbstract<object>` wherever you used the non generic interface before.

Comment: Thanks. My use case is that I need to use it as a parametered type. I think `List<IAbstract>` is a nicer way to do it.